# How it posible read text for docx file, like antiword?

Tags: php, text

Who knows, how read file.docx like antiword for file.doc in php ?
This I used antiword for file.doc and set text in DB

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $developer = $em->getRepository('ProfileBundle:Developer')->findOneById($id);

    if (! $developer) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find a profile.');
    }

    $cv = $developer->getCvDirUri();

    if($cv && file_exists($cv)) {
        unlink($cv);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new DeveloperDirCvType(), array());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();

            $uploader = $this->get('artel.profile.file_uploader');
            $path = $uploader->uploadFile($data['photo']);
            $developer->setCvDirUri($path['url']);
            $content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword '.'chmod o+r /var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);
            if ($data['photo']->getClientMimeType() == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                $content_txt = exec('/usr/bin/abiword --to=html '.'/var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);

            }
            elseif ($data['photo']->getClientMimeType() == 'application/pdf') {
                $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
                $pdf    = $parser->parseFile('/var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);

                $content = $pdf->getText();

            } 
            else{
                $content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword -m UTF-8.txt '.'chmod o+r /var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);
            }


            $url = sprintf(
                '%s%s',
                $this->container->getParameter('acme_storage.amazon_s3.base_url'),
                $this->getPhotoUploader()->uploadFromUrl($path['url'])
            );

            $developer->setTextCv($content);
            $developer->setCvUri($url);


            $em->flush();
```

If file.doc I used antiword and setTextCv($content) and I have text in DB and I upload in amazon, BUT

If this file docx I upload docx file in /upload/Cv/file.docx and create file.html. Then I need setTextCv('text in file html') or if you know another method ? And I dont know how its do it right. Any idea?

Comment: You can try to unzip it and dig around in the file structure.

Comment: how unzip ?  I dont know

Comment: First, you need to learn the structure of a `.docx` file. It is nothing more than a `.zip` file. You can look into Zip classes in the PHP documentation. If you only want to read the text, you can scatter around the file `word\socument.xml`, inside the `.docx` file.

Comment: I edit post, and add description

Comment: So, you want to extract the text and save it to an html file and to a database?

Comment: yes, and I want doc docx and pdf file

Comment: But what exactly isn't working?

Comment: for docx file I nothing to set,
`$content_txt = exec('/usr/bin/abiword --to=html '.'/var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);`
=>convert to html, but this is not I want
dump($content_txt) and have null, 

 if I have doc I do 
`$content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword -m UTF-8.txt '.'chmod o+r /var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);`

dump($content) and I have text. I do to set in DB

Comment: Now I'm even more confused...

Comment: Why ? :) Example for pdf file I use library smalot/pdfparser 
`elseif ($data['photo']->getClientMimeType() == 'application/pdf') {
                    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
                    $pdf    = $parser->parseFile('/var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);

                    $content = $pdf->getText();
                    dump($content); //I have text in file (Output in text form)
`
and I $developer->setTextCv($content);I want parse docx file too but not finde library for them

Comment: So, I wasn't far from what you wanted to do. You can check this: https://github.com/ismael-miguel/docx2txt that I wrote yesterday. You can see what I do and you can try to implement it. The code you will want is from line 38 and on. It won't play well with tables. The code is largely untested and may produce weird results.

Comment: thanks man, I not try but I write code and this code work fir docx file

[my paresr for docx](https://gist.github.com/shubaivan/74079bad119ea0a0140f)

Comment: You really should use the `ZipArchive` class. It's way faster and shorter than doing it yourself. Also, it is a bad idea what you are doing with your XML file. It may give you troubles in the future. But, for the simple purpose, it seems that it will do it's job fairly well.